# Integration by Substitution solved.

Tags: integration

I want to solve this integral.
For integration by substitution, I let
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(t)=\tan\theta.$$
But, I cannot solve for $f(t)$ and $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}f(t)$.
I cannot even find $\frac{dt}{d\theta}$.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: this $\sqrt{(f'(t))^2+1}^3$

Comment: $(f'(t)^2+1)^{3/2}$  ?

Comment: yes, that's right!!

Comment: Maybe integration by parts helps after separating the integral.